# Greasemonkey: Send full page content forward

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, greasemonkey

Is it possible to select the full page content after the document load is ready and send it in an ajax post to another server?

I am trying to test this, I fired up two php server:

`localhost:9000` : This one would receive the data sent from Greasemonkey's script and save it to a file. Test code:

**index.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0) {
    file_put_contents("SOMETHING_AND_IT_IS_POST.txt","");
    $data = var_export($_POST);
    file_put_contents("POSTED.txt",$data);
} else {
    file_put_contents("SOMETHING_BUT_NO_POST.txt",$data);
}
```

`localhost:9001` : Imitating the source of data, hosts only an html file

**post.html**

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<p>Test</p>
<div>
    <p> should work</p>
</div>
<!--<form action="" method="post">
  <p>Is commenting ok?</p>
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> -->
</body>
</html>
```

**Greasemonkey script:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        testajax
// @namespace   test
// @include     http://localhost:9001/post.html
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$( document ).ready(function() {
  console.log( "Loaded!" );

  GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:9000/index.php",
    data: $("body").html(),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    onload: function(response) {
      alert("POSTED!");
    }
  });
});
```

So, in the browser, I open `http://localhost:9001/post.html`, the GM script fires, console.log is working, but the `localhost:9000/index.php` does not receive anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so it is not a solution to the problem above, more like a better way to do it.

I tried to do automation with greasemonkey, that is why it tries to send the data to another place. There is a tool for doing this, called casperJS (built onto PhantomJS, it is also required to run it). Basically, you can write JavaScript, to navigate in the site, select the data you want and post it with the casperjs's ajax util. All of this is documented well.

[casperjs.org](http://casperjs.org/)

[casper ajax](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html?highlight=ajax#sendajax)

[Tutorial: Automating & Scraping with PhantomJS and CasperJS by Chris Hawkes](http://youtu.be/Kefil5tCL9o)

Answer (score 1):

You have to send the data as a `key`/`value` pair:

```
data: {html: $("body").html()},
```

Then look for an incoming `html` property in your `$POST` superglobal.

Comment: It is not working with `GM_xmlHTTPRequest()`, only with `$.ajax()`, it will send a request, but I receive an empty post, also I get an error (console.log): `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:9000/index.php. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

Comment: Odd.. try replacing your `grant` line with this: `@grant GM_xmlhttpRequest`

Comment: Still, gm's ajax won't do anything. It won't even send the post (checked it in firefox's network tab)